# join CDR records from 2 asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have 2 asterisk servers (server_A and server_B), On both I store CDR records in MySql. 
My question:
Is there any way how to join CDR records from both servers, when user from server_A call to user from server_B??

Comment: could you use a customflag to detect from which server the call is?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can automatically append a system identifier to front of the unique IDs by setting systemname in the asterisk.conf file (for each of your boxes):

```
[options]
systemname=server_A
```

Further info:

- http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596517342/asterisk-DB.html#setting_systemname

Answer (score 0):

For each SIP device, either ensure that you define:

```
accountcode=the_user_id+the_server_id
```

... or ...

```
setvar=user_server=the_user_id+the_server_id
```

... where you would naturally replace "the_user_id+the_server_id" with meaningful data.

You can then tweak your MySQL CDRs so that you are storing either "accountcode" or "user_server" as a field.  If you want to get very clever -- and it's likely a good idea for data fault tolerance anyway -- set up MySQL replication between the two servers so you're actually writing to the same Database/Table for your CDR data.

Further reading:

- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variables
- http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html